# A way to find all footway and street interesections in openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I would like to find all intersections of streets with `highway=footway`, that don't have `highway=crossing` tag added.

Right now I have a query:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[highway]["highway"~"primary|secondary|tertiary|residential|unclassified|primary_link|secondary_link|tertiary_link|service"];node(w)->.n1;
way["highway"="footway"];node(w)->.n2;
node.n1.n2["highway"!="crossing"];
out meta;
```

Which works fine until it finds nodes that are not on intersections:

- street changing to footway (street ends and a footway starts just
  after it)
- footway joining with street (footway ends on a street, so no crossing)

Basically I would need to have a way to find an intersection of two ways, such that both of the ways have nodes before and after the intersection - they should not end on the intersecting node.

Is there a way to exclude the above two cases somehow using overpass turbo? Or should I do post processing?

Comment: I'd suggest to take a look at post processing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to exclude the above two cases somehow using overpass turbo?

Not feasible according to what I know and I looked extensively to avoid post-processing.

> Or should I do post processing?

At least I used this solution.